# HTML - how to return to a specific arcicle after processing a web form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to redirect back to specific  on my main page after submitting and processing a Web form.

I have this setup on my mhome page

```
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="#me" class="icon icon-home active"><span>Home</span></a>
    <a href="#work" class="icon icon-folder-close"><span>Work</span></a>
    <a href="#email" class="icon icon-envelope"><span>Email</span></a>
    <a href="#twitter" class="icon icon-twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
    <a href="#facebook" class="icon icon-thumbs-up"><span>Facebook</span></a>
</nav>
```

The webform located on #email, is being processed on a different file (email.php)

What I can't figure out is how to get back to index.php#me after the form is processed, I tried using

```
../index#me
```

but that just doesn't work :S

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Changed the code to try out the hashtags and it just redirects to default article (#me)

```
<?php
header ("Location: ../../index.php#work");
?>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Are you trying to redirect back to the home page from email.php? if so, post the code from email.php so we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with test code my on email.php (cleaned the file up temporarily to test the redirect alone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to include the file extension.

Change:

```
../index#me
```

To:

```
../index.php#me
```